# Android FirebaseListAdapter items always return 0 for one int

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have objects in a firebase database which represent characters in a video game and contain all their stats (attack, defense, health etc). I use a firebaseListAdapter to fill a gridview with custom views showing the characters and some of their stats.

When using Android API 25 or below, this works as expected, but with API 26 and above, all data EXCEPT the health value come through fine, and the health value is always set to 0.

The health variable is simply an int, and is never treated any differently than the other integer values (strength, defense etc) anywhere in the code.

I'll note that adding a listener to the health value alone of any of the characters retrieves the value just fine.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing this?

[image]

```
FirebaseListOptions<PlayerMonster> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<PlayerMonster>()
            .setQuery(mDatabase.child("playerMonsters").child(firebaseId).orderByChild("size"), PlayerMonster.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.monster_grid_single)
            .build();

    monsterFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<PlayerMonster>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, PlayerMonster monsterInstance, int position) {

            // Not getting value for health ONLY, max health and everything else works. Querying health by itself also works.
            Timber.d("monster health is " + monsterInstance.getHealth() + ", max hp: " + monsterInstance.getMax_health());

            // Code here populates the view

        }
    };

    grid.setAdapter(monsterFirebaseAdapter);
```

```
package odyssey.game.balfur.odyssey.firebase_objects;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PlayerMonster extends Monster implements Parcelable {

    private String user_given_nick_name;
    private int experience;
    private int drawableRes;
    private int itemHeldId;

    protected PlayerMonster(Parcel in) {
        user_given_nick_name = in.readString();
        monster_name = in.readString();
        itemHeldId = in.readInt();
        type = in.readInt();
        level = in.readInt();
        health = in.readInt();
        max_health = in.readInt();
        experience = in.readInt();
        size = in.readInt();
        skill1 = in.readInt();
        skill2 = in.readInt();
        skill3 = in.readInt();
        skill4 = in.readInt();
        strength = in.readInt();
        defense = in.readInt();
        magicStrength = in.readInt();
        magicDefense = in.readInt();
        speed = in.readInt();
        skinId = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<PlayerMonster> CREATOR = new Creator<PlayerMonster>() {
        @Override
        public PlayerMonster createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new PlayerMonster(in);
        }

        @Override
        public PlayerMonster[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PlayerMonster[size];
        }
    };

    public int getDrawableRes() {return drawableRes;}
    public void setDrawableRes(int drawableRes) {this.drawableRes = drawableRes;}
    public int getExperience() {return experience;}
    public void setExperience(int experience) {this.experience = experience; }
//    public void addExperience(int experience) {this.experience += experience; }
    public String getUser_given_nick_name() {
        return user_given_nick_name;
    }
    public void setUser_given_nick_name(String user_given_nick_name) {this.user_given_nick_name = user_given_nick_name;}
    public int getItemHeldId() {return itemHeldId;}
    public void setItemHeldId(int itemHeldId) {this.itemHeldId = itemHeldId;}
    public String getMonsterStringName(){ return user_given_nick_name; }

    public PlayerMonster(){}

    public PlayerMonster(String userGivenNickName, String monsterName, int itemHeldId, int type, int level, int health,
                         int max_health, int experience, int size, int skill1, int skill2, int skill3, int skill4,
                         int strength, int defense, int magicStrength,  int magicDefense, int speed, int skinId){
        this.user_given_nick_name = userGivenNickName;
        this.monster_name = monsterName;
        this.itemHeldId = itemHeldId;
        this.type = type;
        this.level = level;
        this.health = health;
        this.max_health = max_health;
        this.experience = experience;
        this.size = size;
        this.skill1 = skill1;
        this.skill2 = skill2;
        this.skill3 = skill3;
        this.skill4 = skill4;
        this.strength = strength;
        this.defense = defense;
        this.magicStrength = magicStrength;
        this.magicDefense = magicDefense;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.skinId = skinId;

    }

    // constructor for monsters w/ image resource. for use in the monsterBattleGridAdapter
    public PlayerMonster(String userGivenNickName, String monsterName, int itemHeldId, int type, int level, int health,
                         int max_health, int experience, int size, int drawableRes, int skill1, int skill2, int skill3, int skill4,
                         int strength, int defense, int magicStrength,  int magicDefense, int speed, int skinId){
        this.user_given_nick_name = userGivenNickName;
        this.monster_name = monsterName;
        this.itemHeldId = itemHeldId;
        this.type = type;
        this.level = level;
        this.health = health;
        this.max_health = max_health;
        this.experience = experience;
        this.size = size;
        this.drawableRes = drawableRes;
        this.skill1 = skill1;
        this.skill2 = skill2;
        this.skill3 = skill3;
        this.skill4 = skill4;
        this.strength = strength;
        this.defense = defense;
        this.magicStrength = magicStrength;
        this.magicDefense = magicDefense;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.skinId = skinId;

    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("user_given_nick_name", user_given_nick_name);
        result.put("monster_name", monster_name);
        result.put("itemHeldId", itemHeldId);
        result.put("type", type);
        result.put("level", level);
        result.put("health", health);
        result.put("max_health", max_health);
        result.put("experience", experience);
        result.put("size", size);
        result.put("skill1", skill1);
        result.put("skill2", skill2);
        result.put("skill3", skill3);
        result.put("skill4", skill4);
        result.put("strength", strength);
        result.put("defense", defense);
        result.put("magicStrength", magicStrength);
        result.put("magicDefense", magicDefense);
        result.put("speed", speed);
        result.put("skinId", skinId);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(user_given_nick_name);
        parcel.writeString(monster_name);
        parcel.writeInt(itemHeldId);
        parcel.writeInt(type);
        parcel.writeInt(level);
        parcel.writeInt(health);
        parcel.writeInt(max_health);
        parcel.writeInt(experience);
        parcel.writeInt(size);
        parcel.writeInt(skill1);
        parcel.writeInt(skill2);
        parcel.writeInt(skill3);
        parcel.writeInt(skill4);
        parcel.writeInt(strength);
        parcel.writeInt(defense);
        parcel.writeInt(magicStrength);
        parcel.writeInt(magicDefense);
        parcel.writeInt(speed);
        parcel.writeInt(skinId);

    }
}
```

```
package odyssey.game.balfur.odyssey.firebase_objects;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import odyssey.game.balfur.odyssey.helpers.Condition;
import odyssey.game.balfur.odyssey.helpers.Helpers;
import odyssey.game.balfur.odyssey.helpers.TalentShorthand;

import java.util.HashMap;

import timber.log.Timber;


public class Monster implements Parcelable {

    String monster_name;
    int type;
    int skill1;
    int skill2;
    int skill3;
    int skill4;

    int max_health;
    int health;
    int shield = 0;

    int strength;
    int speed;

    int defense;
    int magicStrength;
    int magicDefense;

    private boolean canSwap = true;

    int skinId;  // Each separate skin for each monster will have an ID associated with it

    String firebaseId;

    // At start of battle, record monsters stats to make sure buffs stay below certain %
    public int[] baseStats = new int[6];
    // Used to record how many stacks of a buff a monster has. can have between -5 and 5, each
    // Representing 8% change from base stats. All values initialize to 0 by default
    public int[] buffStacks = new int[6];

    private HashMap<Integer, Condition> currentConditions = new HashMap<>();
    private HashMap<Object, TalentShorthand> talentShorthand= new HashMap<>();

    int level;
    int size;

    protected Monster(Parcel in) {
        monster_name = in.readString();
        type = in.readInt();
        skill1 = in.readInt();
        skill2 = in.readInt();
        skill3 = in.readInt();
        skill4 = in.readInt();
        max_health = in.readInt();
        health = in.readInt();
        shield = in.readInt();
        strength = in.readInt();
        speed = in.readInt();
        defense = in.readInt();
        magicStrength = in.readInt();
        magicDefense = in.readInt();
        canSwap = in.readByte() != 0;
        skinId = in.readInt();
        firebaseId = in.readString();
        baseStats = in.createIntArray();
        buffStacks = in.createIntArray();
        level = in.readInt();
        size = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(monster_name);
        dest.writeInt(type);
        dest.writeInt(skill1);
        dest.writeInt(skill2);
        dest.writeInt(skill3);
        dest.writeInt(skill4);
        dest.writeInt(max_health);
        dest.writeInt(health);
        dest.writeInt(shield);
        dest.writeInt(strength);
        dest.writeInt(speed);
        dest.writeInt(defense);
        dest.writeInt(magicStrength);
        dest.writeInt(magicDefense);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (canSwap ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeInt(skinId);
        dest.writeString(firebaseId);
        dest.writeIntArray(baseStats);
        dest.writeIntArray(buffStacks);
        dest.writeInt(level);
        dest.writeInt(size);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Monster> CREATOR = new Creator<Monster>() {
        @Override
        public Monster createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Monster(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Monster[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Monster[size];
        }
    };

    // At start of battle, need to copy an array of each monsters stats and store it in each monster object
    // These values will be checked when buff skills are used to ensure monsters stats do not go over the max buff amount (currently 40% over base)
    public void backupStats(){
        Timber.d("Backing up stats for %s", monster_name);
        baseStats[0] = strength;
        baseStats[1] = defense;
        baseStats[2] = magicStrength;
        baseStats[3] = magicDefense;
        baseStats[4] = speed;
        baseStats[5] = max_health;
    }

    public Monster(){}

    public Monster(int level, String monster_name, int skinId){
        this.level = level;
        this.monster_name = monster_name;
        this.skinId = skinId;
    }

    public int[] getBaseStats() { return baseStats; }
    public void setBaseStats(int[] baseStats) { this.baseStats = baseStats; }
    public String getFirebaseId() {return firebaseId;}
    public void setFirebaseId(String firebaseId) {this.firebaseId = firebaseId;}
    public int getSpeed() {return speed;}
    public void setSpeed(int speed) {this.speed = speed;}
    public int getStrength() {return strength;}
    public void setStrength(int strength) {this.strength = strength;}
    public int getDefense() {return defense;}
    public void setDefense(int defense) {this.defense = defense;}
    public int getMagicStrength() {return magicStrength;}
    public void setMagicStrength(int magicStrength) {this.magicStrength = magicStrength;}
    public int getMagicDefense() {return magicDefense;}
    public void setMagicDefense(int magicDefense) {this.magicDefense = magicDefense;}
    public int getSkill2() {return skill2;}
    public void setSkill2(int skill2) {this.skill2 = skill2;}
    public int getSkill3() {return skill3;}
    public void setSkill3(int skill3) {this.skill3 = skill3;}
    public int getSkill1() {return skill1;}
    public void setSkill1(int skill1) {this.skill1 = skill1;}
    public int getSkill4() {return skill4;}
    public void setSkill4(int skill4) {this.skill4 = skill4;}
    public int getSize() {return size;}
    public void setSize(int size) {this.size = size;}
    public int getMax_health() {
        return max_health;
    }
    public void setMax_health(int max_health) {
        this.max_health = max_health;
    }
    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
    public void setHealth(int health) {
        if (health > max_health) this.health = max_health;
        else if (health <= 0) this.health = 0;
        else this.health = health;
    }
    public int getShield() {return shield;}
    public void setShield(int shield) {
        if (shield > max_health) this.shield = max_health;
        else if (shield <= 0) this.shield = 0;
        else this.shield = shield;
    }
    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getMonster_name() {
        return monster_name;
    }
    public void setMonster_name(String monster_name) {
        this.monster_name = monster_name;
    }
    public String getMonsterStringName(){ return monster_name; }
    public int getSkinId() { return skinId; }
    public void setSkinId(int skinId) { this.skinId = skinId; }
    public boolean isCanSwap() { return canSwap; }
    public void setCanSwap(boolean canSwap) { this.canSwap = canSwap; }

    public HashMap<Object, TalentShorthand> getTalentShorthand(){
        return talentShorthand;
    }
    public void setTalentShorthand(HashMap<Object, TalentShorthand> talentShorthand){this.talentShorthand = talentShorthand;}

    public HashMap<Integer, Condition> getCurrentConditions(){
        return currentConditions;
    }
    public void setCurrentConditions(HashMap<Integer, Condition> currentConditions){this.currentConditions = currentConditions;}
    public void addCondition(int conditionId, int roundsRemaining, double conditionDamagePercent, int addedStacks){

        Condition condition;

        if (currentConditions.containsKey(conditionId)){
            int conditionStacks = currentConditions.get(conditionId).getConditionStacks();

            // If adding one to the current stacks would still be less than the max stacks for that condition, add 1, otherwise do nothing
            if (conditionStacks + addedStacks > Helpers.getConditionMaxStacks(conditionId)){
                conditionStacks = Helpers.getConditionMaxStacks(conditionId);
                addedStacks = Helpers.getConditionMaxStacks(conditionId) - conditionStacks;  // The difference between the max and the preexisting conditions will be the true number of stacks added
            } else {
                conditionStacks += addedStacks;
            }

            condition = new Condition(roundsRemaining, conditionDamagePercent, conditionStacks);
            condition.setStacksAppliedThisRound(addedStacks);
            currentConditions.put(conditionId, condition);
        } else {
            condition = new Condition(roundsRemaining, conditionDamagePercent, addedStacks);
            condition.setStacksAppliedThisRound(addedStacks);
            currentConditions.put(conditionId, condition);
        }
    }
    public void removeCondition(int conditionId){  // Used for calling condition remove skills doi
        if (currentConditions.containsKey(conditionId)){
            currentConditions.remove(conditionId);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It will be helpful, if you add model class too.

Comment: Posted, although I don't think this has to do with the models, as again it only affects certain versions of Android. Perhaps it's something to do with some functions only working on certain API levels or an issue with firebase libraries in certain Android versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a fix, but I'm still uncertain as to why this was an issue in only certain android API levels.

```
public void setHealth(int health) {
    if (health > max_health) this.health = max_health;
    else if (health <= 0) this.health = 0;
    else this.health = health;
}
```

The setHealth() function is called for each object when firebaseListAdapter gets these objects, and when using API 26+, these functions must be called piecemeal or something because when called, the `max_health` value is set to 0, so the condition

```
if (health > max_health)
```

is true, and therefore health was being erroneously set to 0. In older versions of Android, the max_health value is already set correctly by the tim the setHealth() function is called.

I added a check to ensure that `max_health` isn't 0 at the top of the setHealth() function, as a character can't have 0 for a `max_health`

I'd still be interested for curiosity's sake and to possibly help someone down the line in learning why the behavior differs in the different versions of Android, but for the time being I'll consider my original question answered.